Taskpool not working while calling task with Arguments
I am creating a threadpool by using "https://github.com/alugowski/task-thread-pool/" and calling task using submit function but getting error
    int Model::sum(int a, int b)
    {

        return 1;
    }

    void Model::SubscribeMLStatusCallBackFn(const MLStatusReceiveCallbackFn& statusCallback)
    {
        m_MLStatusCallback = statusCallback;
        task_thread_pool::task_thread_pool pool;
        std::future<int> sum_future = pool.submit(&sum, 1, 2);
        sum_future.get();
    }

Error :No instance of function template matches the argument list, argument types are: (std::string, CommandLineArgumentTypes)
But same working on
    std::future<int> sum_future = pool.submit([] { return 1; });

Can someone tell me what error I am doing in calling submit using &sum function

Please show a [mre]. Is sum a static method?

Use a lambda for your submit too (looks like submit cannot handle member functions, and even if it could you still miss the 'this' pointer ). e.g.  call submit like this .pool.submit([this]{ sum(1,2); }

What you can try to invoke the sum method is passing both the function and the instance of the class, and further binding the member function to the object.
std::future<int> sum_future = pool.submit(std::bind(&Model::sum, this, 1, 2));


Actually, you need to provide  to submit (before the arguments for sum) the instance of Model on which you want to call your sum method:
#include <task_thread_pool.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Model
{
public:

    int sum (int a, int b) { return a+b; }
};

int main()
{
    Model model;

    task_thread_pool::task_thread_pool pool;
    std::future<int> sum_future = pool.submit (&Model::sum, &model, 1, 2);
    auto result = sum_future.get();
    std::cout << "result: " << result << "\n";
}


You can also use a lambda function:
    std::future<int> sum_future = pool.submit ([&model] (int a, int b) { return model.sum(a,b); }, 1, 2 );


Both methods gave same error

@Sijith, that's strange, the snippet is working for me but I had to infer what your Model class looks like, so there may be differences that could explain that.
